# Bootstrap Wizard Plugin with a PHP multi-page form?

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a PHP form that is split into 3 separate PHP pages. The first page submits the form info which is then processed by a third party API. The returned (validated) results are then presented in the second PHP page along with a form for further processing.

My question is whether or not there is a way I can integrate this process into the [BootStrap Wizard Plugin](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/) with its tab structure.

e.g. Fill and submit form by clicking on 'next' and have the Wizard plugin move to tab 2. showing the the next PHP page which has been processed.

```
<!-- Wizard -->
    <section class="wizard">

        <!-- Wizard navigation -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab">Next step</a></li>
                <li><a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab">Confirmation</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Wizard progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-line progress-striped">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
            </div>

        <!-- Wizard content -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="step1">
                <h3>This is first step</h3>
            <form method="post" action="myform.php?api=form&step=1">
                <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" />
                <input type="submit" value="continue" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </form>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="step2">
                <h3>Second step content</h3>
            <form method="post" action="myform.php?api=form&step=2">
                <input type="text" name="faxnumber" id="faxnumber" />
                <input type="submit" value="continue" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="step3">
                <h3>This is third final step (completed)</h3>
                <p>Form Process Complete</p>
                </div>

        <!-- Wizard pager -->
            <ul class="wizard pager">
            <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:;">Previous</a></li>
            <li class="next"><a href="javascript:;">Next</a></li>
            <li class="next finish"><a href="javascript:;">Finish</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

   </section>
   <!-- /Wizard -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.wizard').bootstrapWizard({onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                    var wizard = $('.wizard');
                    var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var $current = index+1;
                    var $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
                    wizard.find('.progress-bar').css({width:$percent+'%'});

                    // If it's the last tab then hide the next button and show the finish instead
                    if($current >= $total && $total != 0) {
                        wizard.find('.pager .next').hide();
                        wizard.find('.pager .finish').show().removeClass('disabled');
                    } else {
                        wizard.find('.pager .next').show();
                        wizard.find('.pager .finish').hide();
                    }

                }});
            });
</script>
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is for the first form to show it's results in the second tab of the wizard.

Comment: "I can of course include the code if necessary." You must include the code. It IS necessary.

Comment: @Popnoodles Ok. will do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I would suggest using the bwizard.js and bwizard.css plugin. And add a button to a form, now u going to have to call the action using ajax and not using an actual input of type submit. Using jQuery, on success of "btn_submit" you will taget the 2nd tab to focus to by giving each tab an I'd, or u can use page inspector and target the default I'd of each tab, which if I remember correctly used to be #step1 etc.

Comment: This is helpful. I had a feeling AJAX might be involved. I will look into this I see if I can figure it out. Thank you.